# How do I reverse the order of output in C++? ( With or without recursion)

Tags: c++, recursion, output, reverse

I'm tasked with writing a program that outputs the binary representation of a decimal integer. It uses the decimal 13 for example, where the desired output is 1101.

My problem is, my neither of the functions in my program print this number in the correct order. They both print it backwards from the desired order.

```
int binaryRecursion(int decimalInteger) //This function uses recursion
{

    int remainder = decimalInteger % 2;

    cout << remainder;

    if ( decimalInteger / 2 == 0 )
    {
        cout << endl;
    }else{
        return binaryRecursion(decimalInteger / 2);
    }

    return 1;
}

void binaryNormal(int decimalInteger) //This function does NOT use recursion
{
    while (decimalInteger != 0)
    {
        int remainder = decimalInteger % 2;
        cout << remainder;
        decimalInteger /= 2;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int decimalInteger;
    cout << "Enter your decimal integer." << endl;
    cin >> decimalInteger;

    binaryRecursion(decimalInteger);
    binaryNormal(decimalInteger);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could simply use `boost:dynamic_bitset<>` for the task. It contains a constructor which converts from integer, see [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/example/example2.cpp) ... but that would be rather lazy ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Don't output it directly, but put it in a growing `std::string` which you would reverse finally.

Answer (score 0):

You could store it in a `string` and output the reverse:

```
void binaryNormal(int decimalInteger) //This function does NOT use recursion
{
    string buff = "";
    while (decimalInteger != 0)
    {
        int remainder = decimalInteger % 2;
        buff += remainder + '0';
        decimalInteger /= 2;
    }

    for(int i = buff.length() - 1; i >= 0; cout << buff[i--]);
    cout << endl;
}
```

Or, you could do this for the recursive function (if you don't care too much about the `endl`):

```
void binaryRecursion(int decimalInteger) //This function uses recursion
{
    int remainder = decimalInteger % 2;
    if (decimalInteger / 2 > 0) binaryRecursion(decimalInteger / 2);

    cout << remainder;
}
```

[Here's a working example](http://ideone.com/XssXU3)

Comment: Your return binaryRecursion will skip the cout << remainder... No output there except cout << endl.

Comment: @Tomek Oh yes. Forgot to remove `return`. It must work now, I guess.

Comment: @JohnBupit Thank you; The string option works perfectly! But the recursive example doesn't look like it will output the numbers in any order.

Comment: @user3578959 It will print the number in correct order. [Check this](http://ideone.com/XssXU3).

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should do the trick:

```
void binaryRecursion(int decimalInteger) //This function uses recursion
{
    int remainder = decimalInteger % 2;
    if ( decimalInteger / 2 != 0 )
    {
        binaryRecursion(decimalInteger / 2);
    }
    cout << remainder;
}
```